# Web Method in aspx page not getting executed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-http

I am trying to make an ajax request on page load itself.I am using angular js $http service to get Json data from the web method which is present in my `User.aspx.cs` page .

My Web Method is follows.:

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static List<Users> GetUsers()
    {
        DBUtil objUtils = new DBUtil(); //This is my class for db connection

        List<Users> list = new List<Users>();
        string strQuery = "select * from TM_Users";
        DataTable dt = objUtils.GetDataTable(strQuery);
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            list.Add(new Users {FullName=dt.Rows[i]["FullName"].ToString(),
            UserName=dt.Rows[i]["UserName"].ToString(),
            Password=dt.Rows[i]["Password"].ToString(),
            phNum=dt.Rows[i]["MobileNo"].ToString(),
            EmailId=dt.Rows[i]["EmailAddress"].ToString(),
            Usertype=dt.Rows[i]["UserType"].ToString(),
            CenterId=dt.Rows[i]["HealthCenterID"].ToString()
            });
        }
            return list;
    }
```

There is no problem with the web method.When i try to call web method with the help of $http which is written inside a controller ina separate js file say `Control.js`.My functionality here is,I am using an ng grid ,So to bind that grid with data from database. 
The code as as below:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngGrid"]);

app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $location) {
    //var myData = $http.get("User.aspx/GetUsers");
    $scope.location = $location;
    var url1 = "User.aspx/GetUsers";
    var myData;
    $http.get(url1).success(function (data,status,headers) {
        myData = data;
    }).error(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    })
    $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'myData'
    };

});
```

When i debug what i noticed is the sucess handler is getting executed.But the web method on aspx.cs page is not getting execute.The response i recieve in the success handler data is the whole html of the .aspx web page

Appreciate your Help!!

Comment: add static in webmethod like `public static List<Users> GetUsers()`

Comment: also if it get request add `[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet =false)]`

Comment: Sorry they did'nt solve my problem. I am getting an error stating Object doesn't support property or method 'config' in my controller

Comment: ohh ok change `var myData;` to `$scope.myData=''`

Comment: I thing it is  not related to exception

Comment: aspx page  html appears as a response(i.e in data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your http get call little bit like this.I have added the content type,an empty data object and response type as json.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngGrid"]);

app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $location) {
    var request =
    {        
    method: "GET",
    url: "User.aspx/GetUsers",
    data: {},
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    responseType: 'json'
    }

    $http(request).then(function (data,status,headers) {
        myData = data;
    }).error(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    })
    $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'myData'
    };

});

});
```

Comment: Thank you this works.I would be glad you can tell me what was i doing wrong

Comment: By the way it worked when i made UseHttpGet =true in web method

Comment: you actually need to explicitly tell request regarding the content type of data and response you would expect.

Comment: And one more thing that i have found out is that success and error handlers are depreceated .So it throws an error if we use them.We have use only then method.So remove the error method in your solution

Answer (score 0):

Webmethod should be a `static` method.

Comment: Thank you for reminding ..Edited with static ..Still the same error appears

Comment: data in success handler has the html of the aspx page

Comment: debug and check whether webmethod is called or not.

Comment: No web method is not called

Comment: I think you need to allow webmethod to be called using GET type of request as follows:- [ScriptMethod (UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]